# jenkins multibranch pipeline disable auto node checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently declarative pipeline will do `checkout scm` automatically when hitting first stage.
What I want is to checkout scm within subdirectory only. (so it won't checkout same thing in root directory)

Since it needs jenkinsfile it already checkout once. Plus directory & subdirectory I checkout thrice total...
Is it possible to disable auto checkout in multibranch pipeline using declarative syntax?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add `options { skipDefaultCheckout() }` if you use Declarative pipeline

Comment: just bit more details `pipeline {
    agent any
    options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
    ...}`.  Docs _skipDefaultCheckout
Skip checking out code from source control by default in the agent directive. For example: options { skipDefaultCheckout() }_  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options