# Do Jenkins have to checkout in order to obtain Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to understand a bit about how Jenkins works internally.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585355/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-disable-auto-node-checkout), @Yen (Who asks the question) notes that Jenkins has to checkout the repo  in order to obtain the Jenkinsfile. This doesn't make sense to me, since let's say I have the following Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'my-node' } { 
    stages { .. }
  }
}
```

If Jenkins has to checkout the repo into the agent in order to obtain the Jenkinsfile, how does it know what agent to checkout into? There ought to be a stage in which the Jenkins master obtains the Jenkinsfile **before** it checks out the repo into the agent.
Someone?

Comment: There is https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-33273 about optimizing the Jenkinsfile checkout process. It is already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, it always clone the repository to the orchestrator (also known as the "Master") that manage all the configurations and agents. Then pass all the stages down to the `agent` label in the Jenkinsfile. The reason why you don't have to write where to do the initial clone is because you've done that already when you created the job on Jenkins UI under **Pipeline**.

[image]

The long answer is, it depends on how the Jenkins is configured. Most enterprise deployments of Jenkins tend to use so-called "Master" & "Slave" strategy. Where "Master" is there to purely orchestrate jobs and provide necessary configurations and "Slaves" are to execute the actual actions.

This is where the `agent { label 'my-node' }` block on the pipeline comes in, it instructs the "Master" to make sure all `stages` are executed in `agent` (also known as the "Slave") rather than "Master" itself.

```
Started by user Praveen Premaratne
Obtained toolkit/test/Jenkinsfile from git git@gitlab.co.uk:devops/pipelines/jenkins-pipeline.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Commit message: "Merge branch 'feature/XXXX-2600' into 'develop'"
 > git rev-list --no-walk f83287e56beb57615bc26c2c1f2751665e54fafa # timeout=10
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on devops-jenkins-worker in /home/jenkins/workspace/Toolkit_Build     <<<< Starting the actual work on the worker
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 1234-1234-1234-1234-1234
Cloning the remote Git repository
Avoid second fetch
Checking out Revision fa0fc43e6de5abc2940d0c4ee87fcbba7baba6f6 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
Cloning repository git@gitlab.co.uk:devops/pipelines/jenkins-pipeline.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/Toolkit_Build # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.co.uk:devops/pipelines/jenkins-pipeline.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH key used to checkout GitLab projects
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@gitlab.co.uk:devops/pipelines/jenkins-pipeline.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.co.uk:devops/pipelines/jenkins-pipeline.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f fa0fc43e6de5abc2940d0c4ee87fcbba7baba6f6 # timeout=10
Commit message: "XXXX-1595: Update Jenkins jobs"
 > git rev-list --no-walk fa0fc43e6de5abc2940d0c4ee87fcbba7baba6f6 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] { (hide)
```

As you've probably noticed that Jenkins clones a repository to the "Master" first and once it understand the instructions set within the `Jenkinsfile`, it starts executing the `stages` on another node (in my case `Running on devops-jenkins-worker...`) 1/3 of the way down.

If you have an all-in-one deployment, where single Jenkins deployment is dealing with both orchestrating and carrying out the workload, the `agent { label 'my-node' }` is the same.

I hope this answer give bit more clarity as to what it does.

> Ps: the thread that you've referenced is trying to stop a specific behaviour that clone the same pipeline to "Salve" node again. You can actually see that's happening on the logs above. Notice how the logs on the beginning also start to repeat right after `Running on devops-jenkins-worker...`.

Comment: I didn't quite understand "If you have all-in-one... the agent `agent { label 'my-node' }` is the same"... What did you mean by that paragraph?

Comment: I also didn't understand "The reason why you don't have to write where to do the initial clone is because you've done that already when you created the job on Jenkins UI under Pipeline." ... By the "initial clone" you mean the clone to the master that is done in order to obtain the Jenkinsfile?  Isn't that something that Jenkins takes care of internally, and like, why do I care where this clone is taking place?

Comment: @YoavKlein in an "all-in-one" deployment, you only have a single Jenkins instance. For that it only clone the repo that contains the Jenkinsfile once and execute on the "Master".

Comment: @YoavKlein for the second question, yes by initial clone I meant to "Master" and isn't that what you've asked for "how does it know what agent to checkout into?" Jenkins doesn't know, so it clone it to "Master" first, when it read the Jenkinsfile and instruct the `agent` on the file to clone and execute the pipeline.